# Linux distros won't boot

Tags: linux

I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem anywhere so I'm posting it here. I'm trying to put a couple Linux distros on a laptop, using xboot and a USB drive, and when the computer booted, it went to the xboot menu, let me pick which distro I wanted, started loading it, but freezes right after beginning to load.

So far this happens with mint, Fedora, Fubuntu, and Ubuntu, while puppy, mageia, and dragora appear to work. Thing is, its not just with the laptop but the same thing happens when I try to run any of those ISO's using QEMU on a computer I know works. When I first tried loading Linux a couple months ago, I tried all of those same ISO's (as in the exact same file) and they all worked fine, but now only some do.

Any ideas on why they won't load?

It doesn't really freeze though, because the computer will reboot instantly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, it just won't move past the first loading screen.

After many more searches, it appears some Linux distros need "virtualization technology" and my laptop lacks hardware for this. If anyone knows a way to get around this, let me know. It looks like a dead end though.

Comment: Please clarify a bit. What exactly do you see? Is it a blank/black screen? Have you tried any of the thousands of hits on google for `linux blank screen`?

Comment: It isn't a blank screen. For Mint, Fedora, and Fuduntu it looks exactly like the menu screen, but without the menu. For mint it was the nice silver/grey/black menu background with the Linux mint logo up at the top left, for Fuduntu its black with the Fuduntu log at the top left, for fedora it is just black, but then the menu screen was also just a black background with a text menu.

Comment: Ubuntu, however, appears to load fine when run on the laptop but comes up with a terminal screen, no GUI, and the stuff I read on starting the GUI in Ubuntu didn't work. When I run it in QEMU, though, it appears to load but comes up eventually to a large black screen with a smaller-than usual blinking cursor. It lets me type, but it doesn't seem to be a terminal. I'd guess that might be a separate issue though?
Let me know if I can provide anything else.
Thanks

Comment: Do you see a cursor? Can you move it? Could you maybe add a screenshot or two so we're sure we know what you're talking about? What graphics card are you using?

Comment: I left one out, debian does the freeze-with-menu's-background thing too.
No I dont see a cursor.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2r1zv3b.jpg

And for the computer I'm running QEMU on, my graphics is Nvidia GeForce GT 635. I dont know what the graphics card is on the laptop.
Also, the Mint page on QEMU simply freezes when I hit enter, but on the laptop the menu disappears like the other ones did.